# Batch Renaming multiple files with different extensions Linux Script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, batch-rename

I would like to write a linux script that will move or copy all files with the same filename (but different extensions) to a new filename for all those files, while maintaining their different extensions. In other words:

if I start with a directory listing:

`file1.txt, file1.jpg, file1.doc, file12.txt, file12.jpg, file12.doc`

I would like to write a script to change all the filenames without changing the extensions. For the same example, choosing file2 as the new filename the result would be:

`file2.txt, file2.jpg and file2.doc, file12.txt, file12.jpg, file12.doc`

So the files whose filename do not match the current criteria will not be changed.

Best wishes,

George

Comment: Why file2 match file1 but not file12 ? Same name length, ends with one digit ?

Answer (score 8):

Note: If there's `file1.doc` in variable `i`, expression `${i##*.}` extracts extension i.e. `doc` in this case.

---

One line solution:

```
for i in file1.*; do mv "$i" "file2.${i##*.}"; done
```

---

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# first argument    - basename of files to be moved
# second arguments  - basename of destination files
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Two arguments required."
    exit;
fi

for i in $1.*; do
    if [ -e "$i" ]; then
        mv "$i" "$2.${i##*.}"
        echo "$i to $2.${i##*.}";
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, filename1 is unknown at the time the script is run. I am dealing with hundreds of folders where there will be 6 files, 3 of which have the same filename (a list of numbers and letters that is variable), but 3 different extensions. In each folder there will only be 2 filenames. EXAMPLE: Folder1 contains: filetextwords12.gif, filetextwords12.jpg, filetextwords12.txt, filextwordste23.gif, filextwordste23.jpg, filextwordste23.txt. Folder2 will contain a similar setup (2 filenames of 3 different filetypes each). Thanks! GH

Comment: How should the program know whether to change `filetextwords12` or `filetextwordste23` files? Should `filetextwordste23` also be moved in the similar way `filetextwords12` should be? If you could elaborate a bit more, maybe we could help you...

Answer (score 4):

The util-linux-ng package (most of linux flavours have it installed by default) has the command 'rename'. See `man rename` for use instructions. Using it your task can be done simply as that  
 `rename file1 file2 file1.*`

Answer (score 0):

To handle input files whose basenames contain special characters, I would modify plesiv's script to the following:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Two arguments required."
    exit;
fi

for i in "$1".*; do
    if [ -e "$i" ]; then
        mv "$i" "$2.${i##*.}"
        echo "$i to $2.${i##*.}";
    fi
done
```

Note the extra quotes around $1.